# Translate PHP Json Webservice request TO VB.Net Json Webservice request

Tags: php, vb.net, web-services, json, http-post

I'm asking help because I tried 1000 solution and no one worked with me, probably because I don't know JSON very well and also PHP.
I have to send a request to Webservice and I have a working PHP solution, that I have to translate in VB.net

Here's the code working in PHP

```
//fill in the details of the contacts.userId is obtained from loginResult.
$contactData  = array('lastname'=>'Valiant', 'assigned_user_id'=>$userId);
//encode the object in JSON format to communicate with the server.
$objectJson = Zend_JSON::encode($contactData);
//name of the module for which the entry has to be created.
$moduleName = 'Contacts';

//sessionId is obtained from loginResult.
$params = array("sessionName"=>$sessionId, "operation"=>'create', 
    "element"=>$objectJson, "elementType"=>$moduleName);
//Create must be POST Request.
$httpc->post("$endpointUrl", $params, true);
$response = $httpc->currentResponse();
//decode the json encode response from the server.
$jsonResponse = Zend_JSON::decode($response['body']);

//operation was successful get the token from the reponse.
if($jsonResponse['success']==false)
    //handle the failure case.
    die('create failed:'.$jsonResponse['error']['errorMsg']);
$savedObject = $jsonResponse['result'];
$id = $savedObject['id'];
```

Ok and here is my code in VB.net

Structure Contactdata
        Public lastname As String
        Public assigned_user_id As String
    End Structure

Try
            Dim uri As New Uri("webservice.php")

```
        Dim contactdata As New Contactdata
        contactdata.lastname = "Valiant"
        contactdata.assigned_user_id = "19x1"

        Dim objectJson As String = JavaScriptConvert.SerializeObject(contactdata)

        Dim moduleName As String = "Contacts"

        Dim params As String() = {"sessionName=" & session, "operation=create", "element=" & objectJson, "elementType=" & moduleName}

        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri)
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post
        request.ContentLength = params.Length
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

        Dim writer As New StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream)
        writer.Write(params)
        writer.Close()
        Dim oResponse As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(oResponse.GetResponseStream())
        Dim tmp As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        oResponse.Close()


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

Naturally I imported a reference to a Json library and Imported (Imports Newtonsoft.Json)
That's not the problem, I'm sure I'm doing something wrong with params.

Someone can help me with this?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with vb but i do get the gist of what you are doing. What is the problem that you are having?

Comment: The problem is that if I send this request without Json , the response is that he can't find any "lastname" field, that's normal because he expect lastname and assigned_user_id in Json object format

Comment: In this code I wrote down, I receive an error before the response of the webservice, the app don't reach that point, it returns an error when he reaches this point
`code writer.Close()`
this appened me before even when trying without JSON and it comes when "params" is not correct, so he can't write it and so he can't close the write too

Comment: Should this:    Dim params As String() = {"sessionName=" & session, "operation=create", "element=" & objectJson, "elementType=" & moduleName} Be something like:   Dim params As String = "sessionName=" & session & "&operation=create" & "&element=" & objectJson & "&elementType=" & moduleName   Or does that happen automatically?

Comment: yes you can do also as you suggest, that is a unique string, and I tryied also that before last code, the difference using 'code Sim params As String' is that params is not a 1 only string, but it becomes an array of strings, as params(0) = "sessionName=" & session", params(1) = "operation=create", but the result it must be the same, the problem must be somewhere else.. :(

Comment: In an actual post request. All the key value pairs will have to be an string. In the PHP example, that happens through the library being used to do the post request. Is your VB code doing the same thing?

Comment: OMG OMG OMG OMG DATASAGE Can I kiss you?????????? It works!!!!! You know why i was making it wrong when using a normal string as you wrote?? I forgot some 'code &' -__-'' I was writing only Dim params As String = "sessionName=" & session & "operation=create" & "element=" & objectJson & "elementType=" & moduleName'

Comment: Please post the answer to your own question and mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the working code

In a module

```
Structure Contactdata
Public lastname As String
Public assigned_user_id As String
End Structure
```

Then in my form

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json



Dim contactdata As New Contactdata
contactdata.lastname = "Valiant"
contactdata.assigned_user_id = "19x1"

Dim objectJson As String = JavaScriptConvert.SerializeObject(contactdata)

Dim moduleName As String = "Contacts"

Dim params As String = "sessionName=" & session & "&operation=create" & "&element=" & objectJson & "&elementType=" & moduleName

Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri)
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post
request.ContentLength = params.Length
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Dim writer As New StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream)
writer.Write(params)
writer.Close()
Dim oResponse As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
Dim reader As New StreamReader(oResponse.GetResponseStream())
Dim tmp As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
oResponse.Close()


Catch ex As Exception
MsgBox(ex.ToString)
End Try
```